# Error event listener not working for invalid background-image url in inline style

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple div which is supposed to contain an image. In order to do that, I add the `background-image: url()`. The background url can only be added via JavaScript and not via a class. In order to manage error, I tried to add an error event listener on the div in order to get notified when the url is not good but it does not work.
I would like to avoid to fetch the url manually.

Check the snippet code:

```js
const el = document.getElementById('test');
el.addEventListener('error', () => {
  console.log('ERROR');
});
el.style.setProperty('background-image', 'url(img.png)');
```

```css
.default {
  height: 84px;
  width: 112px;
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="test" class="default"></div>
```

Comment: *The background url can only be added via JavaScript and not via a class.* — why?

Comment: Because it is a custom url which can be provided by a consumer

Comment: Well generally invalid CSS and styles are silently ignored.

Comment: Alright thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use hidden image to capture the error:

```html
<img id="image">
```

```js
const img = document.getElementById('image');

img.addEventListener('load', event => {
  el.style.setProperty('background-image', `url(${event.target.src})`);
});

img.addEventListener('error', () => {
  console.log('ERROR');
});

img.src = 'img.png';
```

Comment: It could be a workaround. But if I use that I could simply do a fetch and check the response. I just wanted to know if I was able to catch error on inline style in a div. But thanks for your time and your reply

Comment: @PierBJX well the advantage of using a constructed Image is that you can check that the URL actually fetches *something*, but also that the result is really an image of some kind.